# Why cannot assign value inside a function to variable declared outside (globaly)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, scope

I don't know why I can't assign a value captured by .hover function to a variable declared globally.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($){

  var receipt;

  $("#cartItems tr.cItem").hover(

        function()
        {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            receipt = $(this).next().children().text();
            console.log(receipt);
        },
        function()
        {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    );

    console.log(receipt);

  });
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<table id="cartItems">
  <tr>
     <td>Lp.</td><td>z:</td><td>na:</td><td>cena netto:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cItem">
      <td>ru</td><td>pl</td><td>16.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="4">some simple text that should be assigned </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

First `console.log(receipt)` (inside `.hover` function) works fine and outputs `some simple text..` and the second outputs nothing.

Please help.

Thank You All for so quick reply. You All are absolutely right about .hover function. My fault. But now I have another related problem. 
I need this value to pass it to "qTip" plugin called like this:

```
$("#cartItems tr.cItem").qtip(
{
    content: receipt,
    show: 'mouseover',
    hide: 'mouseout'
 });
```

Should I merge somehow this calls ?

Comment: The second console.log will only run once, when the enclosing function is executed, at which point nothing will have been assigned to receipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, where you currently have placed the `console.log(receipt)` , `receipt` will not yet have been initialized.

If you want to change this to something more meaningful you can:

1. Move your variable declaration outside of the on load function
2. Call console.log(receipt) in its own function which you can attach to a click event or any other action *after* the load function.

> ```
> var receipt;
>
> jQuery(function ($) {
>     $("#cartItems tr.cItem").hover(
>
>     function () {
>         $(this).addClass("highlight");
>         receipt = $(this).next().children().text();
>         console.log(receipt);
>     }, function () {
>         $(this).removeClass("highlight");
>     });
>
> });
>
> function printConsole() {
>     console.log(receipt);
> }
> ```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sE9He/) demo showing this.

Notice when it firsts outputs the value it's `undefined` since when the page first loads the hover event hasn't fired so the variable is uninitialized. After you hover and click the link it now has a value.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. The second log still logs `undefined` because `receipt` hasn't been assigned a value yet.

Comment: Moving variable declaration before jQuery(function($) { not working. Id there any solution to store this value after execution of .hover is ended ?

Comment: I've added a short jsfiddle demo. You'll have to be more clear what isn't working.

Comment: .qtip( function is not working (end of my question). It's a plugin that pops up small info window and it works fine but i can't pass to it a text taken from .hover element

Answer (score 5):

the "second" call to console.log is actually the first (it occurs when document is ready), and at this moment your var is not defined

Answer (score 3):

The value will only be assigned to `receipt` after the hover functions have been called. You're logging to the console before `#cartItems tr.cItem` has been hovered.

Answer (score 1):

The second `console.log` as far as how it lays out in the code happens before the hover, thus the variable is undefined. After you hover, it properly logs the text of the next tr's children. Here's a jsfiddle, your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/63xKR/

Answer (score 1):

the hover() function is only executed once you actually hover over an element. so what you are writing is basically:

```
var receipt = null;
var documentReady = someFunctionToBeExecutedLater(){ doesnt matter whats in here };
console.log(receipt);
```

as you can see, nobody is actually calling the function (documentReady()), therefore receipt will stay null.